# Is it possible to alter the gear types, e.g., increase memory and/or disk, assigned to a gear in OpenShift Origin?

Tags: openshift-origin

Background for the question (if interested):  I'm looking at possibly using OpenShift Enterprise or Origin to implement a private cloud, to run various in-house enterprise applications (some of which will not be web apps).  If I can't adjust the resources a gear uses, then I probably can't use this PaaS solution, since some of my apps require gigabytes of RAM, and access to a SAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Openshift Enterprise and Origin you can create custom gear profiles.

Origin: http://openshift.github.io/documentation/oo_administration_guide.html#user-resource-management

Enterprise: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Enterprise/2/html/Administration_Guide/chap-Resource_Management.html#Adding_New_Gear_Profiles

Comment: Thanks.  I had seen the first URL, but not the second, which mentions the file I was really looking for: [resource_limits.conf](https://github.com/openshift/origin-server/blob/master/node/conf/resource_limits.conf)